# How do I send a python variable over to javascript? The python is a cgi script?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, post, cgi

I have a javascript file where I am trying to set a variable using data sent from a python cgi script.

I am trying to use the ajax get method, and setting the variable within that method. Here is how I am doing it in the javascript.

```
$.get('cgi-bin/populate_usernames.py', function(data) {
    users = data
});

console.log(users)
```

In the python code, I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

data = ["Bob", "Jim"]
```

For some reason, the console log fails because users is undefined. I think it is because the content type is incorrect for data. Is there a way for me to send a JSON array from the python code so that users has the correct contents of Jim and Bob?

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous. You will have to put the `console.log(users)` inside the `{ }` of the callback you pass to `$.get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple data structures like lists, you can use an external standard like JSON to pass information between two languages.

```
import json
data = ["Bob", "Jim"]
json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

Then pass the json string to the javascript environment in whatever way is possible in your application.

Comment: I figured out that I have to send a JSON object. The main problem is how do I send the json string over to the javascript environment.